# UpperCase selected range in Excel - VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to convert selected cells to uppercase or lowercase. Is there any shortcut keys for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question for SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below function:

```
Sub Uppercase()
   For Each x In Selection
      x.Value = UCase(x.value)
   Next
End Sub
```

For lowercase, use `LCase` instead of `UCase`.